# Does changing landing page URLs to a new domain affect Google Ads SEM performance?

Tags: google-ads-api, google-search, sem

My company is facing an issue where we have to change our site's URLs at scale - close to 200k. These pages will be redirected to a new set of pages with a different domain name (owned by the same organisation).

The aforementioned pages are -

- **Transactional**
- **Rank on organic search keywords** and SEO activity is focussed on them
- Used in our **SEM campaigns** as Landing Pages

The fundamental question is whether changing around 200 URLs in our Google Adwords account would affect the quality score at all? If yes, how much of a hit can we expect?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google Adwords and SEM

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. Obviously, changing the URL will not affect ad copy or keywords (unless you're running dynamic search ads); that portion of the quality score will not change.  If these landing pages are faster, delivery a better customer experience, and lead to higher-quality visits (longer time on page, lower bounce rate, better goal completion), then you will see your quality score improve.  If not, it will fall.